# Change tag groundhogs-day into groundhog-day

Tags: support, status-completed

Can any mod change the tag [groundhogs-day](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/groundhogs-day) into [groundhog-day](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/groundhog-day)?

(Post too small): And to fullfill the quality standards, I must say, euhhh..... please?

Comment: You need not be a mod to do so yourself. You need just click `retag`. I just did.

Comment: Someone with a 5 or more score on groundhog-day should create a synonym.

Comment: @Tshepang In this case, where the tag is used only once, retagging works just fine, and indeed: I could have done it myself. Silly me. But note that retagging is meant for only that and only on one question at a time, not to fix spell errors in a possibly widely used tag-name.

Comment: @iandotkelly ...to keep the spell error floating around here?

Comment: @NGLN - i can see your point but I was thinking that synonyms are intended to map alternative (for which I was also thinking common mis-spellings) to the correct tag

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That was my flub making the tag but it seems to have been fixed.